# Microsoft sign in works without redirect url

Tags: .net-core, oauth-2.0, blazor-server-side, microsoft-account

When I sign in with Microsoft OAuth in my Blazor app, *authenticateResult.Succeeded* is true, even if I don't specify a redirect URI. It's failing as intended for *Google*, if I don't add my URI to the OAuth client.

Imo it shouldn't work without that redirect URI, according to the OAuth2.0 spec:

> The authorization server MUST require public clients and SHOULD
>   require confidential clients to register their redirection URIs.

I'm using *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount 3.0.3* with .NET Core 3.0

> ```
> public class ExternalLoginModel : PageModel
> {
>     public IActionResult OnGetAsync(string externalAuthType, string returnUrl)
>     {
>         var authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
>         {
>             RedirectUri = Url.Page("./externallogin",
>             pageHandler: "Callback",
>             values: new { returnUrl }),
>         };
>
>         return new ChallengeResult(externalAuthType, authenticationProperties);
>     }
>
>     public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetCallbackAsync(
>         string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
>     {
>         var authenticateResult = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("External");
>
>         if (!authenticateResult.Succeeded) // Should be false for Microsoft sign in
>             return BadRequest();
>
>         ...
>
>         return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
>     }
> }
> ```

With the following added to my Startup:

```
        services.AddAuthentication(o =>
        {
            o.DefaultSignInScheme = "External";
        }).AddCookie("External");
        services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(google =>
        {
            google.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
            google.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
        });
        services.AddAuthentication().AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
        {
            microsoftOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientId"];
            microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientSecret"];
        });
```

My App's Authentication settings look like this (I'm actually using localhost:12345 in the settings, but that's not what my app is running on..):
[image]

[image]

Ironically the last sentence might explain it, but I don't even know which flow the *MicrosoftAccount* library is using and I only get generic documentation when googling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fails as intended when using a completely different domain, not localhost with different ports. I guess that's good enough.

Additionally I unchecked "ID token" and "Treat application as a public client", therefore *Authorization code flow* should be used, to my understanding.